# need to know kernel gpg (--kerserver) command addresses -- gpg command

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, gnupg, gpg-signature

I am running Debian `5.10.0-kali7-amd64` amd compiling kernel `linux-5.12-6` when I run

```
gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys xxxxxxxx....
```

command

it gives

> gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host

and when I run

`gpg --recv-keys xxxx`

it gives following

> gpg: key 38DBBDC86092693E: new key but contains no user ID - skipped

> gpg: Total number processed: 1

> gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1

What is above error. on this link it says
https://superuser.com/questions/1485213/gpg-cant-import-key-new-key-but-contains-no-user-id-skipped

> You are probably using the xxxx.org keyserver, which has an owner approval system it will strip all user IDs unless the owner of the corresponding email address has allowed them to be published.

Or how to verify the kernel

For kernel compiling I am using this tutorial https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

It also talks about verifying kernel sign with `gpg --recv-keys xxxx....` again it also gives

```
gpg: key 38DBBDC86092693E: new key but contains no user ID - skipped
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
```

how to resolve the above so I get output of `gpg --recv-keys xxxxx...` something like following

> gpg: key xxxx: 7 duplicate signatures removed

> gpg: key xxxxx: 172 signatures not checked due to missing keys

> gpg: /home/vivek/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created

> gpg: key 79BE3E4300411886: public key "Linus Torvalds torvalds@kernel.org" imported

> gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found

> gpg: Total number processed: 1

> gpg:               imported: 1

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for that particular key are given at:
https://www.kernel.org/signature.html

I cannot vouch for the security of following those instructions, other than to say that they are hosted on kernel.org and delivered via https.

In case the URL mentioned above breaks (gets moved or deleted), I have the broad strokes of the solution listed below. I've removed the parts that specifically refer to gregkh@kernel.org who is associated with the key (RSA key ID 38DBBDC86092693E) you mentioned

```
gpg2 --locate-keys torvalds@kernel.org gregkh@kernel.org
gpg2 --tofu-policy good <RSAKEY_IN_DOUBT>
gpg2 --trust-model tofu --verify linux-5.12-6.tar.sign
```

Comment: I just noticed that Greg Kroah-Hartman (gregkh@kernel.org) is the co-author of the book I've been from O'Reilly entitled "Linux Device Drivers" (available from https://www.oreilly.com/openbook/linuxdrive3/book/).  That said, the acrobatics of authenticating signatures as described above still seems bizarre to me.